# Mat type is same but I get "Pushed vector type is not the same as matrix type in function 'push_back' " error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to reshape the sift descriptor matrix I get into one line and then push it back to another matrix but I get this error **Pushed vector type is not the same as matrix type in function 'push_back'**.

this is my code:

```
Mat get_featuesunclustered( Mat input)
{
  if(!input.data)
    {
      cout << "Image not found !!!" << endl << endl;
    }
  
  //To store the keypoints that will be extracted by SIFT
  vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

  //To store the SIFT descriptor of current image
  Mat descriptor;  

  //The SIFT feature extractor and descriptor
  Ptr<SIFT> detector = SIFT::create();
    
  //detect feature points and compute the descriptors for each keypoint
  detector->detectAndCompute(input, noArray(), keypoints, descriptor);

  if (descriptor.type() != CV_32F)
    {
      descriptor.convertTo(descriptor, CV_32F);
    }
  
  return descriptor;
}

int main(){
  Mat dicodescriptor,labels, feats;
  vector<Mat> dico; // dico contains images

  for(size_t y = 0; y < dico.size(); y++)
      {
         dicodescriptor = get_featuesunclustered(dico[y]);
      
         Mat f = dicodescriptor.reshape(dicodescriptor.rows * dicodescriptor.cols, 1);
         feats.push_back(f);    
      }
}
```

I don't know what wrong with my code, someone can help please ?

Comment: youre reshaping the descriptors to [1x1] Mats with varying **channels**, and channels are part of the type in opencv (please have a look at reshape() docs again). ditch the reshape() and push the descriptors "as-is". also, do not try to convert them to CV_32F. (if they're not, you cannot cluster those anyway, at least with opencv)

Comment: again, please explain, what you wanted to achieve with the reshape()

Comment: my objective is to create a traindata using descriptors Mat to do svm trainning. So to do this `svm->train(feats, ROW_SAMPLE, labels);` Variable feats must have dimension [1xm]. I don't know if you understand what I want to explain

Comment: i do understand, what you want, but there are a few problems with your idea.  different images will have different numbers of features. and an SVM needs same length features. reshaping wont work ever. did you take a look at the "BagOfWords" idea for this ?

Comment: in other words, you should not try to use those features directly for a classification

Comment: Yes i saw **bagofWord** but it doesn't work as I want on my dataSet and moreover I don't want to use kmeans